# Not generating PDF file when php script is run through batch in windows

Tags: php

I have written a script in PHP which generates a PDF file containing an image. When I execute this script through browser it works fine, but when I execute it through a batch file it doesn't work. Could anyone help me figure out why?

Comment: Please edit your question to contain the specific part of your code that is not working, provide any error messages and tell us what you have tried so far. In the current state, your question is unanswerable.

Comment: E:\xampp\php>E:

E:\xampp\php>cd xampp\php\
The system cannot find the path specified.

E:\xampp\php>php "E:\xampp\htdocs\MISNEW\ExpiredLoanList.php"



Warning: fopen(image\logo.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
 in E:\xampp\htdocs\MISNEW\fpdf.php on line 1280
<b>FPDF error:</b> Can't open image file: image\logo.png
E:\xampp\php>pause
Press any key to continue . . .